# Evitar el reinicio de los audios

Tags: android-studio

Tengo el siguiente problema, Cuando ejecuto la aplicación, se ejecuta una de los 2 audios que elegí de forma aleatoria, hasta acá no tengo problemas. 
Cuando giro la pantalla guardo los audios y su posición, pero creo que tengo errores en el "onRestoreInstanceState" porque vuelve a entrar en el condicional para crear un audio aleatorio.

La otra duda es, como puedo agregar audios y dejarlos en una lista de espera, para que se reproduzcan a medida que vayan terminando los que estén en curso.

Editado: La aplicación utiliza dos tipos de layout.

Aquí genero el audio aleatorio.

```
if((!mp.isPlaying()) && (!mp2.isPlaying())) {
        canciones = (int) (Math.random() * 2 + 1);
        if (canciones == 1 && (!mp.isPlaying())) {
            mp.start();
            mp.setLooping(true);
        }else if(canciones ==2 && (!mp2.isPlaying())){
            mp2.start();
            mp.setLooping(true);
        }
    }
```

Aquí guardo.

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    if (mp.isPlaying()){
        int pos = mp.getCurrentPosition();
        outState.putInt("posicion", pos);
        mp.release();

    }else if(mp2.isPlaying()){
        int pos2 = mp2.getCurrentPosition();
        outState.putInt("posicion2", pos2);
        mp2.release();
    }

}
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    if (mp.isPlaying()&& mp !=null) {
        int pos = savedInstanceState.getInt("posicion");
        mp.seekTo(pos);
        mp.setLooping(true);

    }else if (mp2.isPlaying() && mp !=null){
        int pos2 = savedInstanceState.getInt("posicion2");
        mp2.seekTo(pos2);
        mp2.setLooping(true);
    }
}
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Una opción es definir dentro de tu `AndroidManifest.xml` para tu `Activity` que realiza la reproducción la propiedad:

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

Esto evitará que la `Activity` se destruya al girar el dispositivo y se reinicie el audio o trate de obtener otro audio aleatoriamente, ejemplo:

```
<activity android:name=".Activity"
                  ...
                  android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
                  ...
 />
```